# How expensive are transactions in Grails?

Tags: performance, grails, groovy, transactions

I'm looking at performance issues with a Grails application, and the suggestion is to remove the transactions from the services.

Is there a way that I can measure the change in the service?

Is there a place that has data on how expensive transactions are? [Time and resource-wise]

Comment: Profile your application using something like Visual VM and do an A/B. There are too many factors involved to say it's X or Y more/less expensive. It depends on your application. Measure it.

Comment: We found transactions surprisingly expensive in our application. We now separate out our services into a 'transactional' and 'non transactional' version - we managed to get a lot of quick performance wins by doing this, particularly for service methods called within a loop. As @JoshuaMoore suggests, use a profiler to see the impact of transactions in your application.

Answer (score 2):

If someone told you that removing transactions from your services was a good way to help performance, you should not listen to any future advice from that person. You should look at the time spent in transactions and determine what the real overhead is, and find methods and entire services that are run in transactions but don't need to be and fix those to be nontransactional. But removing all transactions would be irresponsible.

You would be intentionally adding sporadic errors in method return values and making your data inconsistent, and this will get worse when you have a lot of traffic. A somewhat faster but buggy app or web site is not going to be popular, and if this doesn't help performance (or not much) then you still have to do the real work of finding the bottlenecks, missing indexes, and other things that are genuinely causing problems.

I would remove all `@Transactional` annotations and database writes from all controllers though; not for performance reasons, but to keep the application tiers sensible and not polluted with unrelated code and logic.

If you find one or more service methods that don't require transactions, switch to annotating each transactional method as needed but omit the annotation at class scope so un-annotated methods inherit nothing and aren't transactional. You could also move those methods to non-transactional services.

Note that services are only non-transactional if there are no `@Transactional` annotations and there is a `transactional` property disabling the feature:

```
static transactional = false
```

If you don't have that property and have no annotations, it will look like it's ok, but `transactional` defaults to true if not specified.

There's also something else that can help a lot (and already does). The `dataSource` bean is actually a proxy of a proxy - one proxy returns the connection from the pool that's a being used by an open Hibernate session or transaction so you can see uncommitted data and do your queries and updates in the same connection.  The other is more related to your question: `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` which has been in Spring for years but only used in Grails since 2.3. It helps with methods that start or participate in a transaction but do no database work. For the case of a single method call that unnecessarily starts and commits an 'empty' transaction,  the overhead involved includes getting the pooled connection, then calling `set autocommit false`, setting the transaction isolation level, etc. All of these are small costs but they add up. The class works by giving you a proxied connection that caches these method calls, and only gets a real connection and invokes these method on it when a query is actually run. If there are no queries and the only calls are those transaction-related setup methods, there's basically no cost at all. You shouldn't rely on this and should be intentional with the use of @Transactional annotations, but if you miss one this pool proxy will help avoid unnecessary work.