# Getting rid of "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" and performances with @Transactional on read methods

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, transactions

I've introduced HibernateTransactionManager in my project, because we need to use transactions for some service methods. I've also followed the best practice to inject the SessionFactory into the DAO layer instead of implementing the HibernateDaoSupport.

Now in some read methods that are not annotated with @Transactional I got the error:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

I know how to solve it, just add the @Transactional all over the place. But my colleagues are worried about performance. Should also read methods like:

```
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class).add(Restrictions.eq("color", color)).addOrder(Order.asc("createDate")).list();
```

be annotated with @Transactional?

I've also read this post [Some clarification about Spring @Transactional annotation on a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300483/some-clarification-about-spring-transactional-annotation-on-a-method) that discourage to use this annotation in DAO layer, so I don't see what is the best practice for getting rid of the issue **AND have good performances on read methods**.

Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the [Spring TransactionManager](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) abstraction, you must always mark all Service methods with:

- `@Transactional`
- `@Transaction(readOnly = true)` for read-only methods

That's because Hibernate will no longer manage transaction, but instead it will delegate this responsibility to the Spring framework. Unless you mark each transaction-boundary method with the `@Transactional` annotation, Spring cannot associate the current Thread with a Hibernate Session and an associated JDBC Connection.

So, using `@Transactional` is not an option.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, so the readOnly = true is paving the way to good performances in read methods, or should I expect a deterioration of perf. introducing these annotations to all my methods? Actually I'm reading other posts like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390963/how-expensive-are-transactions-in-grails that suggests to move read-only operations in sepatate services... What do you think?

Comment: The read-only transactional annotation is fine. It will not affect your app performance. Usually the performance is more affected by less optimal db queries.